# xcode "compile source as" override for specific file

Tags: xcode, compiler-errors, objective-c++

I have a project that has to be set to "Objective-C++" for the "compile source as" value (no, "according to file type" will not work in my main project).  I am having a problem with a file I got from a framework (specifically OpenFeint) that has compile errors when compiled as "Objective-C++".

```
error: pointer of type 'void *' used in arithmetic
```

I can get the file to compile in a test project that is set to "according to file type" for the "compile source as" value.  So I am wondering how to set a specific file to compile as Objective-C?  If I can get this one file to compile as Objective-C in my real project, everything should work in perfect harmony.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: You should complain to the developers of OpenFeint to fix their code.  Pointer arithmetic on `void*` pointers is not defined by the C standard; gcc is being nice to you and doing the pointer arithmetic *as if* they were `char*` pointers, but it's still wrong.

Comment: I have contacted the developers of OpenFeint and they are having an engineer look at it for me.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The developer of OpenFeint got back to me and got me a pre-release of their next release.  it fixes this problem.

I might add that they where very responsive.

Comment: Technically, I did answer your question which was "How do I compile a file as a specific type", I think it's slightly unfair to mark the question as answered by yourself. Just sayin'.

Comment: I disagree.  The questing clearly states "override for *specific file*" not "specific type".

Thanks for your time though.

Comment: Yep. That's the answer I provided, which explained how to change the type *for a specific file*. Whatever.

Comment: Rob has a point here... He answered your question related to how to compile the source file as.... Claiming the answer was the OpenFeint developers fixed their source in the next release really is not an answer to your question since the question was never asked.

Answer (score 10):

Right-click the file in the **Groups and Files** list in Xcode, and select **Get Info** from the contextual menu.

You can then change the type of the file in the **General** tab of the info window. You probably want the file to be of type `sourcecode.c.objc`.