# ZipArchive linker errors for "Compile Sources as Objective-C++"

Tags: ios, linker-errors, php-ziparchive

I am using Xcode 4.3.2, target architecture is armv7 and base sdk is iOS 5.1.

I try to use ZipArchive on some test project, and it works fine with the build settings set to "According to File Type". But when I change the settings to "Compile Sources as Objective-C++", which is the requirement for my main project, then compiler throws a lot of errors, (parse and semantic issues).

My problem then, is to compile .c files in this Objective-C++ project. So I saw this question, [[here]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2137541/xcode-compile-source-as-override-for-specific-file) and changed the type of files from ".c" to ".c.objc". Now, I am getting linker errors. The usual ones found when people import ZipArchive into their project. Like this ->

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386: "_zipOpen", referenced from: -[ZipArchive CreateZipFile2:] in ZipArchive.o
```

And I think the solutions given on those linker error questions are for project sources that are compiled as "file-type", not for Objective-C++. Any idea what could be done?

Comment: have you managed to solve it?